# How to create a triangle kernel in python?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, kernel

I am experimenting with different kernels for image processing. But I could not find any library supporting triangle filter, so I decided to make my own. I took reference of python code for making a Gaussian kernel and wrote this:

```
def triangle_kernel(kerlen):
    lim = kerlen//2 + (kerlen % 2)/2
    x = np.linspace(-lim, lim, kerlen)
    kernel1d = 1 - np.abs(x)
    kernel2d = np.outer(kernel1d, kernel1d)
    print(kernel2d.shape)
    return kernel2d
```

Is this correct? I tried convoluting images with this kernel but the output was highly distorted. what mistake am I doing? how do I create the kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement it like this:

```
import numpy as np

def triangle_kernel(kerlen):
    r = np.arange(kerlen)
    kernel1d = (kerlen + 1 - np.abs(r - r[::-1])) / 2
    kernel2d = np.outer(kernel1d, kernel1d)
    kernel2d /= kernel2d.sum()
    return kernel2d

print(triangle_kernel(4))
# [[0.02777778 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.02777778]
#  [0.05555556 0.11111111 0.11111111 0.05555556]
#  [0.05555556 0.11111111 0.11111111 0.05555556]
#  [0.02777778 0.05555556 0.05555556 0.02777778]]
print(triangle_kernel(5))
# [[0.01234568 0.02469136 0.03703704 0.02469136 0.01234568]
#  [0.02469136 0.04938272 0.07407407 0.04938272 0.02469136]
#  [0.03703704 0.07407407 0.11111111 0.07407407 0.03703704]
#  [0.02469136 0.04938272 0.07407407 0.04938272 0.02469136]
#  [0.01234568 0.02469136 0.03703704 0.02469136 0.01234568]]
```

Comment: why is there need to divide by 2 and then divide by the sum? also how do you decide the calculating r?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde As `r` is calculated, it advances in increments of 2 (e.g. for `kerlen=5` it is `[-4 -2  0  2  4]`). `kernel1d` is calculated to advance in increments of 1 (e.g. `[1 2 3 2 1]`). This way, the resulting kernel is such that the "next" value beyond the boundaries would be exactly 0 (e.g. if you take the first row of the result for 5 the increment is always 0.01234568, so going "one step further" would not contribute anything because the kernel would already be zero). The final normalization is just so the kernel sums up to one and the resulting image has the same overall energy.

Comment: I don't get why there is no library function for the filter though

Comment: @ShantanuShinde Well you could simplify the function doing `kernel1d = scipy.signal.triang(kerlen)`, although the result is slightly different for even numbers (also, seems that [`scipy.signal.triang`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.triang.html) is being dropped in newer version so you would have to use [`scipy.signal.sawtooth`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sawtooth.html) instead, something more convoluted like `kernel1d = ((scipy.signal.sawtooth(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, kerlen + 2), 0.5) + 1) / 2)[1:-1]`).